# How to set different placeholders for DateFromToRangeFilter?

Tags: django-forms, django-widget, django-filters

I am using django_filters in my project and one of them is a DateFromToRangeFilter. This filter generates two input fields in your templates, figuratively - 'From' and 'To'.

There is no problem to set a similar attribute for these fields. For example:

```
end = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(
        widget=django_filters.widgets.RangeWidget(
                attrs={'placeholder': 'yyyy-mm-dd'}))
```

But I cannot understand how to set different placeholders (or any other attributes for each of the fields). Like 'Enter the start date' for field 'From' and 'Enter the finish date' for field "To".

Can someone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default `MultiWidget` passes all `attrs` to each subwidget. To bypass this, you would have to subclass `RangeWidget` and provide separate `attrs` parameters for each of the `from/to` widgets.

Something like the following:

```py
class MyRangeWidget(RangeWidget):
    def __init__(self, from_attrs=None, to_attrs=None, attrs=None):
        super(MyRangeWidget, self).__init__(attrs)

        if from_attrs:
            self.widgets[0].attrs.update(from_attrs)
        if to_attrs:
            self.widgets[1].attrs.update(to_attrs)
```

Comment: I think the second "if" should be this: `if to_attrs:
            self.widgets[1].attrs.update(to_attrs)`

Answer (score 1):

I use the below in production to have two different placeholders.

```
import django_filters
from django_filters.widgets import RangeWidget, SuffixedMultiWidget
from jobsboard.models import Job 

class DurationRangeWidget(SuffixedMultiWidget, RangeWidget):
    suffixes = ['min', 'max']

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        super().__init__(attrs)
        self.widgets[0].attrs.update({'placeholder': 'from'})
        self.widgets[1].attrs.update({'placeholder': 'to'})


class JobsConsultantFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    hirer = HirerFilter(name='hirer', max_length=255)
    duration = django_filters.RangeFilter(name='duration', widget=DurationRangeWidget)
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ['duration', 'pay', 'hirer', ]
```